# Last <tr> is not on a separate row. It is appearing parallel to second last row in which I used colspan and rowspan

Tags: html, css, dom, html-table

I have a table in which 1st column is spaning 8 rows while others are parallel to it. Second last row should be parallel to it while spaning 3 rows and 3 columns. Last row should be on a separate row it's first column take 1 col while second takes 3 cols.

I want this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcVCw.png)

This is my code

```
    <table class="table discovery mb-0 ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="w-25">Discovery URL</th>
                <th>Issue type</th>
                <th>Plugin Id</th>
                <th>Severity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="discoveryurl">
                <td class="text-start br-b0" rowspan="8">
                    opc.tcp://echo:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer
                </td>
                <td class="text-start">
                    Anonymous authentication enabled
                </td>
                <td><a href="#" target="_blank">10001</a></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col pe-0 text-start">High (7,3)</div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="results high">
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-start">Message Security Mode None</td>
                <td><a href="#" target=" _blank ">10006</a></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col pe-0 text-start">Medium (6,5)</div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="results medium">
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-start">Security Policy None</td>
                <td><a href="#" target=" _blank ">10009</a></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col pe-0 text-start">Medium (5,4)</div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="results medium">
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-start">Self-signed client application certificates trusted</td>
                <td><a href="#" _blank ">10010</a></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col pe-0 text-start">Medium (5,4)</div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="results medium">
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-start">Auditing disabled</td>
                <td><a href="#" target=" _blank ">10002</a></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col pe-0 text-start">Medium (5)</div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="results medium">
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span class="active"></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-start subs" colspan="3" rowspan="3">Hiding 3 random issues.
                    <a href="#">subscribe</a> to view all.
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="last-row">
                <td class="text-start br-rb">
                    opc
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" colspan="3">
                    <ul class="error">
                        <li>
                            Https 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and this is result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rwtg.png)

Comment: You have really rather hidden the most important part of this, in one of your images only: _'Are you able to make the "hiding" row span three rows? (To be the same height as 3 "normal" rows on the table)'_ - that simply makes no sense, with the given structure. There _are_ no three rows next to this, that _could_ determine this height. And there is no "normal" row height either, because the height of your rows is dependent on their content.

Comment: What size do you want that rowspan=3 to actually be? It would make more sense to me if that were just rowspan 1 with say padding and content. Then the first item could be rowspan=6 and everything would understand what heights are required (mostly set by content).

Answer (score 0):

Your first `<td>` has a rowspan of 8, however I only count 7 `<tr>`s in your `<tbody>`.

Bigger tables can be tricky with multiple col- and rowspan. You can draw the table on a paper and then number the cells you want to connect. Maybe that helps visualizing and determining the correct value for col- and rowspans.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

We need to be careful of a couple of things here

There aren't as many rows in the table as is supposed by the first item spanning 8.

There is no concept of 'normal' height of a row - at least maybe to us who are used to wideish screens and see just one line of text per entry (but what would happen on a narrow viewport?). We need to tell the system what the height of a row is. In this set up 'normal' is whatever the content needs (plus perhaps a bit of padding.)

This snippet alters things so the cell previously designated to take up 3 rows takes up one but is made taller than the others with additional padding. And the cell that was to take up 8 rows now takes up just 6.

Things will adjust to narrower viewports/table.

```html
nt this enter image description here This is my code


<table class="table discovery mb-0 ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="w-25">Discovery URL</th>
      <th>Issue type</th>
      <th>Plugin Id</th>
      <th>Severity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="discoveryurl">
      <td class="text-start br-b0" rowspan="6">
        opc.tcp://echo:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer
      </td>
      <td class="text-start">
        Anonymous authentication enabled
      </td>
      <td><a href="#" target="_blank">10001</a></td>
      <td>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col pe-0 text-start">High (7,3)</div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="results high">
              <span class="active"></span>
              <span class="active"></span>
              <span class="active"></span>
              <span class="active"></span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-start">Message Security Mode None</td>
      <td><a href="#" target=" _blank ">10006</a></td>
      <td>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col pe-0 text-start">Medium (6,5)</div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="results medium">
              <span class="active"></span>
              <span class="active"></span>
              <span class="active"></span>
              <span class="active"></span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-start">Security Policy None</td>
      <td><a href="#" target=" _blank ">10009</a></td>
      <td>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col pe-0 text-start">Medium (5,4)</div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="results medium">
              <span class="active"></span>
              <span class="active"></span>
              <span class="active"></span>
              <span class="active"></span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-start">Self-signed client application certificates trusted</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" _blank ">10010</a></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col pe-0 text-start ">Medium (5,4)</div>
                        <div class="col ">
                            <div class="results medium ">
                                <span class="active "></span>
                                <span class="active "></span>
                                <span class="active "></span>
                                <span class="active "></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-start ">Auditing disabled</td>
                <td><a href="# " target=" _blank ">10002</a></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col pe-0 text-start ">Medium (5)</div>
                        <div class="col ">
                            <div class="results medium ">
                                <span class="active "></span>
                                <span class="active "></span>
                                <span class="active "></span>
                                <span class="active "></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-start subs " colspan="3 " rrowspan="1 " style="padding: 20px 0 20px 0; background-color: pink; ">Hiding 3 random issues.
                    <a href="# ">subscribe</a> to view all.
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr rclass="last-row ">
                <td rclass="text-start br-rb ">
                    opc
                </td>
                <td rclass="text-start " rcolspan="3 ">
                    <ul rclass="error ">
                        <li>
                            Https 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```